# Strange delay using js .resize event

Tags: jquery, delay

Excuse me, please, for my question may be foolish, but I'm a beginner in scripting and realy need some help.
I want an element to slide down from above the page when button is pressed, and slide back when button is pressed again. This element should fill 100% of the container it is placed in, so at first I gather the container's height with .css('height') and then set this value to element size and to it`s position. Then goes some .animate effect.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    //gather dimentions 
    var x=($("#screenctr").css("height"));    
    var y=parseFloat(x);
    var z=(y*-1 + 'px');
  $(".roll").css("height", x);
  $(".roll").css("top", z);
    //slides from above
  $(".bloop").click(function(){
    $(".roll").animate({
       top:'0px'}, "slow");
    $(".bloop").css("display","none");
    $(".bzook").css("display","block");
    });
    //slides back
  $(".bzook").click(function(){         
    $(".roll").animate({
       top:z}, "slow");
    $(".bzook").css("display","none");
    $(".bloop").css("display","block");
    });
  });
```

It works fine. But also I want it to change size and position when window resizes. So I write the same script for
    `$(window).resize(function(){}`

It still works, but very strange. At first, when page is just loaded, everything is ok, and after a first resize it falls from above properly, too. But since then, when it's expected to hide back, nothing happen for a few seconds, and then it begin to drag upward very slowly. Down again — no problem, up — again draging after a long delay.
Does anyone knows what it can be caused by? Thank you.

Here is the page: http://production.zukaty.ru/

Comment: Most likely it's due to the animation being started once for every time the resize event happens, which could be hundreds if not thousands of times per resize. I suggest implementing a throttle on the resize event so that it'l do the animate when the user is done resizing.

Answer (score 1):

When you using .animate() method on $(window).resize() add .stop() method, because function in $(window).resize() will be called number of times per second, and .stop() stops previous animation, so use it like this:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
   $(".roll").stop().animate({ ... });
}
```

This should solve your problem.